# Can lithium batteries and lead acid batteries be used together?

Tags: lead-acid, lithium

If I have the two batteries with same voltage but different capacity, can [lithium batteries](https://www.grepow.com/page/lifepo4-battery.html) (the lfp battery like this type) and lead-acid batteries be used together?

Comment: Your question is unclear, you probably mean not only using them together (different batteries used separately in the same device, that's OK) but you also want to **connect them together** (in parallel or series). That last one is a big **NO**. NEVER connect batteries with different chemistries together. For example, the charging requirements of Lead Acid batteries and Lithium batteries are **very different**. If you do this you **will** damage one or both of the batteries and you risk overheating and fire. **So don't!**

Comment: Thanks, so I may use it together if there is the same chemistry? but different capacity or voltage.

Comment: Again: No. **Only** combine batteries that are: The same chemistry AND the same model AND the same capacity AND charged to the same voltage AND similar age. **All five** of these conditions need to be met to combine batteries safely. In practice that means: ready-made battery packs and cells bought all at the same time that you combine into a battery pack. Do anything else and again you risk damaging batteries. Even combining identical batteries where one is older (more worn out) than the other can result in overcharging the older cells. It is simply not worth the risk!

Comment: also need similar life span...ok, i got it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

They can **used** together, if they're powering different circuits, or different parts of the same circuit.

If you're doing a quick test, they can be put in series with clip leads to power something, but not for long. Do not approach a full discharge. Do not wire them permanently. Do not attempt to charge them. They are a temporary power source, nothing more.

Never, ever, put them in parallel.